# Mapping problem with object coordinates (Blender Internal)

Tags: texturing

So there is this option in Blender Internal where you can use the object coordinates for mapping.

[image]

https://gyazo.com/8c0c9d12d190f0db084b8d725cf092f9

However, I don't want it to be applied to another object but rather the same object the texture is being used on. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Object coordinates uses the origin of selected object as new coordinates, I think what you want to use is Generated.

Comment: Thank you, but when I use generated the texture stretches in a weird way.

Comment: Try to apply the scale of the object.

Comment: I actually did that for the last months or so, but since it was getting annoying over the time I thought that using the object coordinates would make it much easier. :/ Here is what I want to do: https://gyazo.com/f850490740743dfdbf010dee7975c8da Even though one of the cubes is smaller, the texture size stays the same. But when I move one of the cubes, the other cubes texture begins to move too.

Comment: You can rotate and scale the object to manipulate the texture

Comment: I know, but that is the problem. I want it to stay on the object, without any other objects being able to manipulate it.